# Creating an Excel workbook in isolated storage

Tags: silverlight, excel, storage

Can I create an Excel workbook in the isolated storage area using server side data in Silverlight?

Answer (score 2):

Not as you describe it. [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage(VS.95).aspx) is stored on the client and server code (like WCF services) is executed on the server.

You could create the XLS/XLSX on the server and then stream it down to Silverlight, which can then save it into Isolated Storage.

Alternatively, you could generate the XLSX (or XLS [in Silverlight 4](http://silverlight.net/getstarted/silverlight-4-beta/)) in Silverlight using data from the server. Here is [an example of using Silverlight to create a PPTX](http://www.dotnetsolutions.co.uk/blog/archive/2009/07/21/writing-ms-office-documents-from-silverlight-3/), but it should be a start point for creating an XLSX (the format information for which [is available on microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/bb265236.aspx))

Answer (score 1):

An Excel workbook, stored in xlsx format, is just an XML document. If you can form the releveant XML and save it with an xlsx extension then you have your Excel workbook.